# Enable programmability in InfoPath 2007

Tags: development, infopath, visual-studio

I have a 2007 InfoPath form that I'm hosting on my SharePoint (not web-enabled) to which I'd like to add some C# code to make it more robust.

I am well aware that InfoPath 2007 is programmable with a variety of managed and unmanaged languages. My desire is to use C# through VSTA (Visual Studio Tools for Applications) to add some spiffy, new features to my InfoPath form. Everything that I've looked at has mentioned going to:

`Tools -> Form Options -> Programming -> Form Template Code Language`

and changing the selection to C#. I would be happy to do this, except that there *IS* no `Form Template Code Language` section. I've seen the screenshots of the window in tutorials and videos. Under the `Programming` category on the left, there are *TWO* section: `Custom Task Pane` (which I have) and `Form Template Code Language` section, which is nowhere to be found on mine.

On top of this, any place where I should be able to click "Edit Form Code" (such as in a button's properties window) to automatically launch VSTA and edit the event code, the button is also missing.

I have installed VSTA through the Programs and Features interface, and as far as I can tell, I have MSXML 6.0 installed (the .dll for it exists in my System32 folder) which are both requirements of this process according to the MSDN tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251747%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

I've tried repairing my Office 2007 install, and I've tried removing InfoPath altogether and reinstalling just that piece, but nothing has worked. Would someone please help me before I pull the *rest* of my hair out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the privileges to do so, make a change in the system registry.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\12.0\InfoPath\Designer\RestrictedFeatures]
"CodeAllowed"=dword:00000001
```

Restart InfoPath and the `Programming` option should be available from the `Tools` menu.

Comment: This did the trick! Fantastic! Thanks. I was unable to edit the value as my current user, so I had to go in as admin and go through USERS instead of CURRENT_USER, but it's here now!

Comment: How did you even discover this solution?

Comment: Sorry, one of the security organizations upstream was blocking something that borked the CSS styling on the entire site, so I couldn't really get back in and answer your last question.  

Honestly, I don't really remember where I found the solution, only that Google led me to it several years ago when we ran into the same problem.  I actually put it into a .reg file so that I could run it whenever group policy reset the value.